# I am trying to return sales based on two date columns. Is this way correct?

Tags: sql

I have a sales table with 3 columns: date1 which is the actual transaction date for both store sales and online sales, date2 on which order was placed online and a sales($) column showing total sales for the particular date (both store and online). The date2 will be null if the sale has happened in store as store will have only one date which is date1.

```
date1     |date2    |sales
6/1/2015   ?         1000
6/1/2015  6/1/2015   2000
15/2/2015 10/2/2015  3000
16/3/2015  ?         5500 
.
.
.
```

I have used the case statement on the two date columns to return the total sales for a year by each date.

Here is my code:

```
case when date2 is null then date1 else date2 end as purchase date,
sum(sale) as total_sales
where date1 between '2015/1/1' and '2015/12/31'
and date2 between '2015/1/1' and '2015/12/31'
group by 1
;
```

My expected output should have 365 rows with total sales combined for both online and store sales for every day starting '1/1'2015' but I am getting 7000 rows. What changes should I make to my code?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Purchase_Date, SUM(sales) as Total_Sales
FROM (
    SELECT coalesce(date2, date1) as Purchase_date, sales 
    FROM [MyTable]
) t
WHERE Purchase_Date > = '20150101' and Purchase_Date < '20160101'
GROUP BY Purchase_Date
```

Notice what I did with the dates. The different format is the ISO-8601 unseparated format, and for historical reasons it's the best option to use when working with Date-only values in Sql Server. Full Date+Time values should use the more-familiar `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff` ISO-8601 separated format. Some other databases don't have the same historical quirk, or prefer other formats, but what you see here will still work pretty much anywhere.

I also used two comparisons, rather than `BETWEEN`, where the upper bound is actually the next day with an exclusive rather than inclusive boundary (`<`, not `<=`). This is the better way to be sure you get the whole range you want, and nothing you don't.

Or we can re-write this to not need the nested SELECT. It might even run faster... but we have to repeat the `COALESCE()` a lot:

```
SELECT coalesce(date2, date1) As Purchase_Date, SUM(sales) as Total_Sales
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE  coalesce(date2, date1) > = '20150101' and  coalesce(date2, date1) < '20160101'
GROUP BY coalesce(date2, date1)
```

Comment: @PratikChoudhary . . . This question is clearly *not* about SQL Server, given the `group by 1`.  Why did you accept this answer?  Also, you should tag the question with the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 1):

i think the right syntax should be ,

```
select sum(sale) as total_sales, 
  case 
    when date2 is null then date1 
    else date2 
  end as purchase date
from table_name
where date1 between '2015/1/1' and '2015/12/31'
and 
where date2 between '2015/1/1' and '2015/12/31'
group by sale;
```

another note about the date, to use between , you should use filed data type of date not varchare
 and there is another syntax version for date like that

```
where date2 between #2015/1/1# and #2015/12/31#
```

in case of you could not use quotes for whatever reason

Comment: How can I use where keyword twice and group it by sale? It should be grouped by date.